# How do you check whether heteroscedastic-consistent estimators fix your error variance problem?

Tags: least-squares, regression-coefficients, residuals, standard-error, heteroscedasticity

I am running an OLS regression, and have non-constant error variance (residuals vs fitted looks like a fan opening up to the right).

I have tried a number of power transformation but they seem to make the residuals vs fitted look worse. I am trying employing heteroscedastic-consistent SE estimators, such as HC0, HC1, HC2, and HC3. Is there a good diagnostic for checking whether these HC estimators alleviated the issue?

Comment: One of the tests for heteroskedasticity is White's test. More informally, one can inspect the difference between non-robust and robust s.e.'s.

Comment: @Michael I've inspected the difference in SEs, and the robust SEs are larger, as expected. But I'm not sure if that tells me whether I can trust the SEs. Are robust SEs always an automatic fix? I suspect not. I will give White's test a try.

Comment: "Are robust SEs always an automatic fix?"---you will probably find the answer to be uniformly "yes" from the empirical econometrics community.